# What does ":" mean in this Java statement?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, foreach

```
for (Season time : Season.values() )
system.out.println (time+ "\t" + time.getSpan());
```

I see an example for enumeration using `:`. What does this mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the Java syntax for a [foreach loop](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).

The loop will iterate over all the items in the collection of objects returned by `Season.values()` one at a time, putting each item in turn into the `time` variable before executing the loop body. See this closely [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work) for more details on how the foreach loop works.

Comment: Oh I see. I am used to seeing `as` in PHP.

Comment: @Doug: in PHP you use  `as`. Example: `foreach($array as $val)`

Comment: @codaddict yeah, I made the correcton. You're way ahead of me!

Answer (score 1):

It is just a token to separate the iterating variable on the left from the array on the right in the [**new for-each loop**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

Answer (score 1):

It's java's version of `foreach`.

It's a shorthand version of

```
for (int i = 0; i < Season.values().size(); i++) {
    Season time = Season.values().get(i);
    System.out.println(time + "\t" + time.getSpan());
}
```

(exact details depend on what it is that Season.values() is returning, but you get the idea)

As Michael points out, while the above example is more intuitive, foreach is *actually* the equivalent of this:

```
Iterator<Season> seasons = Season.iterator();
while (seasons.hasNext()) {
    Season time = seasons.next();
    System.out.println(time + "\t" + time.getSpan());
}
```

Comment: Actually, it is short-hand for the Iterator-based equivalent (since it works with anything that is Iterable).

Comment: In what universe is using a for to do an indexed iteration over a container more intuitive than using Iterator semantics.  Each to their own I suppose..

Comment: @dsmith - when I say "more intuitive", I meant in terms of explaining what foreach does.  Since it's still structured as a `for`-loop, I think it's easier for people to relate what's going on if they're seeing a for-each construct for the first time